# Circular reference when making state management system typesafe

Tags: typescript, circular-reference, state-management

My state management system in an old project uses MobX. Recently I wanted to make it work with SSR (as I have had success with that in newer projects).

The idea was to have a store manager that manages all the stores, which the stores can also access to be able to read and modify other stores. This works fine with JavaScript, but TypeScript makes it a problem.

I have managed to isolate the problem into a reproductible example. You can run this in the TypeScript playground to see the issue.

```
/**
 * The manager holds all the stores in the application
 */
class StoreManager<T extends Record<string, InitializableStore>> {
  public stores: T = {} as any

  constructor(
    public instantiators: { [K in keyof T]: (manager: any) => T[K] },
  ) {
    for (const [name, creator] of Object.entries(instantiators)) {
      this.stores[name as keyof T] = creator(this)
    }
  }

  public async init() {
    console.info("Initializing stores")
    await Promise.all(Object.values(this.stores).map((x) => x.init()))
  }
}

export type Manager = StoreManager<Stores>

/** 
 * This class represents a store which should have access to the manager
 */

class InitializableStore {
  constructor(protected manager: Manager) {}

  public init(): void | Promise<void> {}
}


/** 
 * Helper function for creating a store factory
 */
const createStoreFactory = <S extends InitializableStore>(
  storeClass: new (manager: Manager) => S,
) => (manager: Manager) => new storeClass(manager)


/**
 * Example store set up
 */

class StoreA extends InitializableStore {
  public init() {}

  public meow() {
    console.log("Meow")
  }
}

class StoreB extends InitializableStore {
  public init() {
    const { storeA } = this.manager.stores
    storeA.meow()
  }

  public woof() {
    console.log("Woof!")
  }
}

const storeA = createStoreFactory(StoreA)
const storeB = createStoreFactory(StoreB)

/**
 * Defining the stores for the manager here
 * */
const stores = { storeA, storeB }

export type StoreMapReturn<
  T extends Record<string, (manager: Manager) => InitializableStore>
> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[K]>
}

/**
 * This errors, because there's a circular reference
 */
export type Stores = StoreMapReturn<typeof stores>
```

Since the stores need to have access to the manager, the types are super complex and don't actually work because there's a circular reference. In a perfect situation, it would work like this:

- The manager can be accessed in any store
- The manager is not a global object imported from a file (so it can be created on the fly and is fully encapsulated)
- The stores are fully typesafe when accessed from the manager

Comment: Add language tags to question to get attention

Comment: @Mannoj TypeScript is literally the first tag...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the compiler must infer the following chain for `Stores` type :

```
type Stores = typeof stores > createStoreFactory > Manager > StoreManager<Stores> > Stores 
//        ^                          circular                                      ↩
```

Above circular reference cannot be resolved. If you hover over `const storeA` initializer, you get:

> 'storeA' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

This error statement does a pretty good explaining job: we can annotate one of the `const` variables with an explicit type to end circular type resolving ([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=72&ssc=6&pln=70&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUgVALAppAtgQwHZoOaIE6TwD2ANgCYDOkaJJkALkpBfUXolQJYYNNoAO-EpwDGaepyIYoIYOBEk0FKgGVW7ALKYc+ADyxIiAB71EGSpABKiEWzK6WebtgA0kAJIZOEmpwBeaABGJIhqbIgAfBGQAN5QkPwArsGizOocAFxwkAC8sQC+1FSYAJ7g8bYYjoki6gAU8ZAJycIikNwsmD7qFFkxkADaANLtPADWiCVEAGZwALpZdehYuHhZpQCUudGww3OQ+S7xW3FNTdNskHWVLINYKIhuIuzibPszkADygQBWNvQAOjM9CcHDqHXoXU4rzwFA2J0aZ0YnAoAJY4QoA3uyCUkAmU1msH2eWeiBhdWRcMR+XiNPiSRSbSUJQwbW43jqCLOkBupEQAO4FzqACJPN5ocI-M40hjhRtEWgAO5obyQAAKeCIKBR-JoJDq3z+tQBADcaIkwZS0ek4QD0Pw6nUjFsctEjAKvPROfDaeA6cZ+Gx6AwSvxkFoVvhcpAwpptKtdLGOBFyqAYDI4PAUTzFMpIOx+OwKMDijL2JBFVmRPBmMREuRCGgTTiRCIOFRWLxkMsdHgZHJ5LmqGKfJKgiEk7EKlJqrU2HVC0RTLVEGRUPH8FkI72Tgdyk0Ga1RhyNlkTUROGuAD7qzXa4u6c+X6L9Gl08BpyAZgASiBIYYIaZElZCQpEgC4CFJcRpTQMtkGmNA5zwMpoDkG5gyg0wkwAMUQ9QSmjRNDBMMwLBHCV-HHUJ0giBomnRdgAGEhyyDBEEVK4e1WLcNzwF1ohUI5+M43ieMjPjtkgNiOIYxBmKUCgll4+VUzADMAFEjDQFAhGQWTmEQYNEn4ftygUBSY3SABBYjTHMYdPQogJgmo8IpwPFpUnZL1dzpDzGVQRAiEVTl3LOXkQgBEgiGwEUNCCxU5V9OlzLzJMACFbNIhzxV8ZyJ3SMLDy8z1QtOcKZ2DfpZJswo8itLj8GtDFERqu0Es5X16U8tpFSIGYysRCL+Wi2LhQAdX66YAEIkqaN9ynoUNkBwvC2BKfQsvsjxHLyqik2iPIlPEsSd0k2AzMquCrKyVakI2pMrMOnkXiw9JcPuupHvldC4PS273rW5DE3SdLnsw1z2A+-CvtBlS0wzAARRBpnZDBsC7OCqAgzHGoIJB2AzWR5Cu2SqDyarrLcWTMv9IxAzwYMlrDSzwi0fhrHoRI8AwXR4gMYw7IsaxbDwexHGcNxjt7U7VmE8i9pcg74me8qmmGUY8UmD4iSyTnuYwWBlv0PYU3m8oAyDEMWaTcnWbjDnDIN3RmaC2YyYiIA)):

```
type StoreFactory<T extends InitializableStore> = (manager: Manager) => T

const storeA: StoreFactory<StoreA> = createStoreFactory(StoreA)
const storeB: StoreFactory<StoreB> = createStoreFactory(StoreB)
```

If that is too repetitive with each store, you can instead define `Stores` first in a top-down approach ([sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=73&ssc=50&pln=65&pc=1#code/PQKhCgAIUgVALAppAtgQwHZoOaIE6TwD2ANgCYDOkaJJkALkpBfUXolQJYYNNoAO-EpwDGaepyIYoIYOBEk0FKgGVW7ALKYc+ADyxIiAB71EGSpABKiEWzK6WebtgA0kAJIZOEmpwBeaABGJIhqbIgAfBGQAN5QkPwArsGizOocAFxwkAC8sQC+1FSYAJ7g8bYYjoki6gAU8ZAJycIikNwsmD7qFFkxkADaANLtPADWiCVEAGZwALpZdehYuHhZpQCUudGww3OQ+S7xW3FNTdNskHWVLINYKIhuIuzibPszkADygQBWNvQAOjM9CcHDqHXoXU4rzwFA2J0aZ0YnAoAJY4QoA3uyCUkAmU1msH2eWeiBhdWRcMR+XiNPiSRSbSUJQwbW43jqCLOkBupEQAO4FzqACJPN5ocI-M40hjhRtEWgAO5obyQAAKeCIKBR-JoJDq3z+tQBADcaIkwZS0ek4QD0Pw6nUjFsctEjAKvPROfDaeA6cZ+Gx6AwSvxkFoVvhcpAwpptKtdLGOBFyqAYDI4PAUTzFMpIOx+OwKMDijL2JBFVmRPBmMREuRCGgTTiRCIOFRWLxkMsdHgZHJ5LmqGKfJKgiEk7EKlJqrU2HVC0RTLVEGRUPH8FkI72Tgdyk0Ga1RhyNlkTUROGuAD7qzXa4u6c+X6L9Gl08BpyAZgASiBIYYIaZElZCQpEgC4CFJcRpTQMtkGmNA5zwMpoDkG5gyg0wkwAMUQ9QSmjRNDBMMwLBHCV-HHUJ0giBomnRdgAGEhyyDBEEVK4e1WLcNzwF1ohUI5+M43ieMjPjtkgNiOIYxBmKUCgll4+VUzADMAFEjDQFAhGQWTmEQYNEn4ftygUBSY3SABBYjTHMYdPQogJgmo8IpwPFpUnZL1dzpDzGVQRAiEVTl3LOXkQgBEgiGwEUNCCxU5V9OlzLzJMACFbNIhzxV8ZyJ3SMLDy8z1QtOcKZ2DfpZJswo8itLj8GtDFERqu0Es5X16U8tpFSIGYysRCL+Wi2LhQAdX66YAEIkqaN9ygDIMQzDSyMWjcqaqyJMrIAbniWT0u29J0v2mklrwYN6FDZAcLwthOA4DbBhGbg8UmD4kwoBYRPEsSd0kr69j3eRKrgmySReLD0lwpCSjqHb5XQuDMshslofCWH8IRk6kbB2TejW9gsYep68mq6y3EOkHynAIA)):

```
export type Stores = {
  storeA: StoreA;
  storeB: StoreB;
}
export type StoreFactories = { [K in keyof Stores]: (manager: Manager) => Stores[K] }

const storeA = createStoreFactory(StoreA)
const storeB = createStoreFactory(StoreB)
const stores: StoreFactories = { storeA, storeB }
```